# How to make speak Marathi/Hindi language in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I'm working on speech processing project where I'm getting user voice from the mic as a input to the raspberry pi and convert to other language and again that converted text is speak by raspberry pi.

Everything works fine when speak language is in english but when it is Hindi/Marathi then it speaks this

> "\u092e\u0930\u093e\u0920\u0940 \u0915\u0940\u092c\u094b\u0930\u094d\u0921"

rather that this

> "मराठी कीबोर्ड"

So what can I do, so it should speaks only what I want, not some encoded stream

Thanking in advanced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe those (u092e, etc) are Hindi [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters. Whatever software you're using to convert those characters into speech apparently doesn't handle them. You need to check its documentation relating to non-English Unicode to see if it can be enabled, or switch to another package that supports Hindi text-to-speech.

UPDATE

With the additional information that the package used is [espeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/), it looks like it does have a Hindi language option. Unfortunately the documentation describes this option as 'initial naive implementations which have had little or no feedback and improvement from native speakers', so your results may be less than spectacular.

From [the espeak documentation on language files](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/languages.html):

> A number of Voice files are provided in the espeak-data/voices
>   directory. You can select one of these with the -v 
>   parameter to the speak command, eg:
>
> `espeak -vaf`
>
> to speak using the Afrikaans voice.

In your case the appropriate option is `hi` for Hindi, per the [ISO 639-1 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes). You'll need to run espeak using that parameter:

`espeak -vhi`